# Is there a way to use numpy slices to do cyclic permutation?

Tags: arrays, numpy, slice

so I was wondering if there is some trickery with slices that would allow me to do cyclic permutations of an array. Basically what I want to do know if there are integers `i,j,k` such that:

```
> x = np.arange(10)
> print x[i:j:k]  
      [9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

and

```
> x = np.arange(10)
> print x[i:j:k]  
      [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
```

I thought the natural syntax would be:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(10)
print x[-1:0]
```

but that returns an empty array (and it kinda makes sense...). Also tried other combinations of slices and nothing worked. I could do it in other ways, but this would be so neat and short... :P

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand. `x[i:j:k] == x[i:j:k]`.

Comment: He is looking for a slicing method to accomplish what numpy.roll does, in both directions.

Comment: Sorry @SteveTjoa I've meant two different sets of i, j and k which would perform the two different permutations. I used the same letters just for economy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `numpy.roll()` or some stride tricks, but other than that I'm pretty sure the answer is no, there is no 3-integer slice that will return what you want.

Comment: `numpy.roll` creates a new array. I think the OP wants a O(1) time complexity solution.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is not possible because to do what you are asking for, numpy needs to make a copy of the array and slicing creates a view not a copy. As Benjamin has already mentioned, check out `numpy.roll`.